# Swift - NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requested the number of rows for section (1) which is out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working with UITableViews for the first time and I'm having some problems.
For context, my tableView has 1-2 sections. A URLRequest is called for 5 different "usernames". For each username, it checks if it's "valid" or "invalid". If it's valid, it gets appended to the Data Source array for the first section (Section 0). If it's invalid, it gets appended to the Data Source array for the first section (Section 1). The tableView is then reloaded and displays the data correctly.
The user can tap on one of the cells in the Invalid section (Section 1) to correct the invalid name to make it valid. A URL Request is initiated again and the name should now be valid.

1. `tableView.beginUpdates()` is called.
2. The corresponding name is removed from the Invalid section Data Source array.
3. The cell is deleted. (Only if it's not the LAST cell in the Invalid section.)
4. If the cell is the last one in the Invalid section, the whole section is deleted.
5. The corrected name is appended to the Valid section Data Source array.
6. `tableView.endUpdates()` is called.

Here's what happens code-wise:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    users.invalid.usernames.remove(at: indexPath.row) // Removing value from Data Source

    if users.invalid.usernames.count == 0 { // Section (1) Data Source contains no values.
        // Deleting Section (1) because it only contains one row which needs to be deleted.
        let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
        self.tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
    }
    else { // Section (1) Data Source still contains values, so only delete the corresponding row.
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Other code is ran and then the tableView ends updates.

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Now, when the error happens, it doesn't explain which line it came from but it says `Requested the number of rows for section...` which I can only assume is related to the tableView function: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

Here's my code for that:

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if users.invalid.usernames.count == 0 { // If Section (1) Data Source is empty, don't show Section (1).
        return 1
    }
    else { // Section (1) Data Source contains data, show both sections.
        return 2
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { //Gets called once for each section that exists.
    /* Since the Section (1) was deleted, this function should only be called once.
     */
    if section == 0 {
        return users.valid.usernames.count // Section (0) Data Source count will always be at least 1.
    }
    else if section == 1 { // Theoretically shouldn't even happen in this case.
        return users.invalid.usernames.count // Return Section (1) Data Source count.

    }
    else { // Will never happen.
        return 1
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss for solving this issue. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Try without the begin/end updates. I can't see a need for them in this case. The end update shouldn't be in a separate asynchronous dispatch. Also, idiomatically you should use `isEmpty` rather than `count==0`

Comment: I need some method for updating the tableView when the name is added to the section 0 data source though. I've tried reloadData() as well :/

Comment: There isn't enough code here to see what your problem is. What is here, in isolation, looks ok, so your problem is somewhere else. I suggest starting by removing the begin/end update calls as this may help you find where the problem is as updates won't be deferred.

Comment: Solved problem. The error was being caused in cellForRowAt. Not sure why, but it was trying to reference attributes of the section that no longer existed. I fixed it by ensuring that that code only ran if there was ACTUALLY 2 sections.